# Firebase text-to-speech extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I have enabled Text To Speech in my Firebase project

https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/text-to-speech

As per description

"Any document writes to this collection will trigger a Cloud Function that does the following:

- Generates an audio version of the same text
- Stores it in Cloud Storage in the specified path
- Writes the path to the Storage object back in the same document.
  "

The last step isn't happening. Is there some additional configuration required to enable this?  Documentation is not helping.

Also, how can I configure Collection Path that is other than at the root?

Thanks

Comment: So the answer is that the filename of the generated audio file in Storage is the Firestore document ID which triggered the cloud function.    

I still don't know how to set the Collection path other than root though.

Comment: Hi @user8865059. From your response this could be a documentation update. Could you clarify what you mean by setting the collection path? Is this different from what you provided when installing the extension?

An feature request has been created for tracking this question/scenario https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-extensions/issues/208

Comment: I resolved my issues.  But, at this link: https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/text-to-speech
...this is incorrect "Writes the path to the Storage object back in the same document."  It does not write back.

Comment: I filed an issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-extensions/issues/248

Comment: @DarrenAckers you are linking the speech-to-text, but this question concerns the Text-to-speech extension

Answer (score 0):

See comments above regarding document and storage paths.